# Passing the UIPickerViews selected title to a string. (Not in didSelectRow)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView`. What I want to do is get the rows title and pass it to a string.

The datasource of the `UIPickerView` is not an `array`, but the integer of row in the `titleForRow` like so:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(row)];
```

I cannot do like this:

```
int selectedRow = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *self.rowTitle = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

because there is no array as the datasource. Is there a way to get the rows title without passing a string from `didSelectRow` to my method?

Comment: What's wrong with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @([self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0])];`?

Comment: This worked. Can you post that as an answer, so I can accept it?